# How to show sweetAlert Validation Delete Dialog in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I am developing an ASP MVC 5 web application using SQL Server. I am trying to delete a profile (client in database) via a button with javascript function.

Clicking on the button, the profile is deleted but the validation dialog doesn't appear. I don't know what the reason is but I doubt that there is an issue with the javascript code.

I tried also to create another button without submit, in order to verify the sweetAlert process. And it worked well.

This is my View :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Client", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
 <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" onclick="remove()">
    }
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">function remove() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover your profile!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
.then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
        swal("Poof! Your profile has been deleted!", {
            icon: "success",
        });
    } else {
        swal("Your profil is safe!");
    }
});
}
  </script>
```

My Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, Client cmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientManagement cdb = new ClientManagement();
            if (cdb.DeleteClient(id))
            {
                TempData["Message"]= "Client Deleted Successfully";
            }
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE :**
View :

```
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" onclick="remove()">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function remove() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover your profile!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Client/Delete",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    swal("Poof! Your profile has been deleted!", {
                        icon: "success",
                    }).then(function () {
                        window.location.href = "/Home/Index"
                    });

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            swal("Your profil is safe!");
        }
    });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You are using `Html.BeginForm`, So the form is submitted. Hence you are not getting the alert message. Convert to button i.e. `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` and `if (willDelete) {
        //Submit the form here or use $.ajax() to call to delete the profile then redirect
    }`

Comment: @Satpal thx for the answer and sorry for the late, I didn't see your comment only now.
yes I tried that as my first solution but my problem is with submiting,I don't know how to do that, i tried with onSubmit but it didn't work

Comment: @Satpal I updated my code like you suggest please take a look thx

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update onclick default behavior but you're not using preventDefault in your javascript code.

```
event.preventDefault()
```