# How to redirect to another page after submitting an alert in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I am developing an ASP MVC 5 web application.

In one of my page, I am trying to redirect the user to the home page after sending mail and this will be after showing a SweetAlert Dialog.

Indeed, the process must be in this order:

> 1. Click on Button Confirm
> 2. Showing alert dialog which contains Ok button
> 3. Click on Ok in this dialog
> 4. Close the alert dialog
> 5. Redirecting the user to Home page

The problem is that the process in working for me in this following wrong way:

> 1. Click on Button Confirm
> 2. Redirecting the user to Home page

This is my view :

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" style="margin-left:-270px;" onclick="SendEmail()">
```

```
<script>
    var SendEmail = function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",


            success: function (data) {

                swal("Good job!", "Your order has been confirmed with success :)", "success");
                window.location = "/Home/Index";
            }

        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `swal("Good job!", "Your order has been confirmed with success :)", "success")
.then(() => {
  window.location = "/Home/Index";
})`

Comment: @Satpal it works ! a lot of thx !! can you please writen as answer for the future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises)

```
swal("Good job!", "Your order has been confirmed with success :)", "success").then((value) => {
    window.location = "/Home/Index";
});
```

Comment: if you have a good knowledges in javascript and jquery can you please take a look of my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091989/how-to-show-sweetalert-validation-delete-dialog-in-asp-mvc
Thx

Answer (score 3):

You want that user clicks the ok button and performing redirection then;

```
swal({
  title: 'Good job!',
  text: "Your order has been confirmed with success :)",
  type: 'success',
  showCloseButton:true
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.dismiss === 'close') {
        window.location = "/Home/Index";
  }
});
```